# Beans Java Based Configuration in Spring Framework, don't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I am reading [this article](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_java_based_configuration.htm) about Spring Java Based Configuration. I am creating an example similar to the one in this tutorial, but I'm using Maven for the build process.

I have added the following dependencies to my project: `spring-core`, `spring-bean`, `spring-context`, `spring-context-support` and `spring-asm`.

The problem is that when I try to execute my application I obtain the following error message:

```
feb 13, 2013 10:26:49 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@4ba4536d: startup date [Wed Feb 13 10:26:49 CET 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: CGLIB is required to process @Configuration classes. Either add CGLIB to the classpath or remove the following @Configuration bean definitions: [helloWorldConfig]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:327)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:222)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:620)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:73)
    at org.andrea.myexample.myJavaConfiguration.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:13)
```

Reading online I have understood that to use these annotations (`@Configuration` and `@Bean`) I have to add the `spring-asm` dependencies to my project. I have tried but it didn't work.

This is my entire `pom.xml` file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.andrea.myexample</groupId>
<artifactId>myJavaConfiguration</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>myJavaConfiguration</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the very same tutorial page it is stating that you need to have the CGLib jar in your classpath (emphasis added):

> Let us have working Eclipse IDE in place and follow the following steps to create a Spring application:
>
> > ...
> >     3 - Because you are using Java-based annotations, **so you also need to add CGLIB.jar** from your Java installation directory and ASM.jar library which can be downloaded from asm.ow2.org.
> > ...

With Maven, you'll need to add the following dependency into your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

[Source](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-javaconfig-example/)

Comment: Worked like a charm!!

Answer (score 4):

Add the below depedency in your pom it should work.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

For The  [**<kbd>Article Which u have Read</kbd>**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_java_based_configuration.htm) .

To Make It Work u just Add the[**<kbd>CGLIB Jar</kbd>**](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) File into your Project.

Download the Jar from ***`CGLIB Jar`*** link  and ***`Add`*** it to your Project

If u r using MAVEN then, you need to include the CGLIB library manually, just declares it in Maven **`pom.xml`** file.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```